# Analytical solution to a nonlinear ODE $\dot x = cy(1-xy) - \beta cx$ and $\dot y = xc(1-xy)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, closed-form, nonlinear-system, stability-in-odes

Is it possible to find an analytical solution to the following system of ODEs: $\dot x = cy(1-xy) - bcx$ and $\dot y = cx(1-xy)$? I can find fixed points and do stability analysis but I am looking for an analytical solution if possible. Solutions in special cases will also potentially be helpful.

Comment: That is a non-linear coupled system. It is rather the exception than the norm for a closed-form solution to exist. But perhaps you can get somewhere when $c=1$ and $b=0$ then for $x,y\neq 0$ you have $x'/y = y'/x$ so that $x x' = y y'$ which I believe can be separated and solved to show that the solutions must satisfy $x^2-y^2=C_0$ for some constant $C_0$. But please check it for yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer (but way too long for a comment):

- Trivial case $c=0$: In this case the solution is given by
  $$
  x=x_0\\
  y=y_0
  $$

If $c\neq0$ a simple rescaling $t\to c\cdot t'$ of the variable allows us to remove $c$ from the equations and therefore we can without loss of generality only consider the case of $c=1$.

- Case $\beta=0$: In this case we can simply calculate (similar to the comment from Nap D. Lover but we only need $\beta=0$)
  $$
  x\dot x-y\dot y=0\\
  \Leftrightarrow\frac{\partial}{\partial t} x^2-\frac{\partial}{\partial t} y^2=0 \\
  \Leftrightarrow x^2-y^2=C
  $$
- General case: if we consider $\frac{dx}{dy}=1-\frac{\beta}{1-xy}$, I was not able to solve this by hand and the software Maple produces a solution only in terms of the higly loaded WhittakerM/W functions
  $$
  \frac{(1+\beta)WhittakerM(-\frac{2+3\beta}{4\beta}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{(x-y)^2}{2\beta})+(yx-y^2-1)WhittakerM(\frac{\beta-2}{4\beta}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{(x-y)^2}{2\beta})}{(1+\beta)WhittakerW(-\frac{2+3\beta}{4\beta}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{(x-y)^2}{2\beta})+2\beta(yx-y^2-1)WhittakerW(\frac{\beta-2}{4\beta}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{(x-y)^2}{2\beta})}=C
  $$

For some special cases of $\beta$ this will simplify to more standard functions such as $\beta=\pm 1$.